# Add <i> tag inside of an anchor tag just before the <span> tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html code:

```html
<div id="outerDiv" class="cls">
  <ul id="ul">
    <li id="li">
      <a id="link1" href="#">
        <span>Click me</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How do I in jQuery add an `<i>` tag just before the `<span>` element so the HTML is rendered as:

```html
<div id="outerDiv" class="cls">
  <ul id="ul">
    <li id="li">
      <a id="link1" href="#">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-check"></i>
        <span>Click me</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Time to review learn.jquery.com?  https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/#moving-copying-and-removing-elements

Comment: Tried .before, but have been unsuccessful

Comment: Tried .insertBefore but still doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: .before script code Please add bottom of your code. it will work

Comment: `before` is exactly what you need. If it's not working for you then there's an issue in your code. As you haven't shown it to us, we can't really help you any further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [**`.before()`**](https://api.jquery.com/before/):

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#link1 span').before('<i class="zmdi zmdi-check">Some Text</i>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerDiv" class="cls">
  <ul id="ul">
      <li id="li">
          <a id="link1" href="#">
              <span>Click me</span>
          </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This still renders the same HTML as per the original question

Comment: @user3596206, wrap your code with `$(document).ready(function(){...});` as in the updated answer:)

Comment: This didn't work. The HTML that I'm trying to generate is: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerDiv" class="cls">
  <ul id="ul">
      <li id="li">
          <a id="link1" href="#">                                                                                              
              <i class="..."></i>
              <span>Click me</span>
          </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

Comment: @user3596206 you are missing script close tag </script>

Answer (score 0):

.before script code add bottom of your code like below code. it will work

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerDiv" class="cls">
  <ul id="ul">
      <li id="li">
          <a id="link1" href="#">
              <span>Click me</span>
          </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#link1 span').before('<i class="zmdi zmdi-check">Some Text</i>');  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add jquery-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( "<i></i>" ).insertBefore( "#link1 span" );
  $('#link1 i').addClass('zmdi zmdi-check');
</script>
```